# java intellij - how to build directory-based project?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Total newbie here.

I hired a developer to create a java project using IntelliJ.
He provided me a github link and I downloaded a *zip of the project.
After unzipping, I looked in the folders and see a hidden /idea folder.
After installing IntelliJ, I then File->Open and selected the root folder of the unzip.
It appears to load in the project explorer of IntelliJ.
I even have an option for Build Project.
However, after I click the Build Project button, it does nothing. Instead I see a message in Event Log: "cannot start compiler: The SDK is not specified for module ...."

The main.java class is buried a few directories down from the root directory.
I checked the main.xml and it correctly paths to the main.java.

What am I missing to build this project?
It isn't clear to me if I selected the correct directory (the root) with the File->Open operation.

I know - very newbie question here - please don't blast me too hard in your reply. I'm probably not even asking this question in the correct manner.

Comment: File, Project Structure, choose Project SDK

Comment: IDEA is already bundled with JDK. You have to change the project one to yours.

Comment: okay I was able to set the SDK. But for some reason whenever I exit IntelliJ, and then open it again, it doesn't save my projects structure settings and I have to enter the settings every time. Very annoying. Is that normal?

Comment: Please check idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") for errors/warnings.